# about requirejs,to require 'jquery' can not with path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

if I use requirejs require jquery like this :

```
requirejs(['../js/lib/jquery','../js/lib/lib'], function ($,lib) {
    var lib = new lib();
    $(function () {
        //somecode
    })
});
```

the run result is : **$ is not a function**

after use require.config:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '../js/lib'
});
requirejs(['jquery','lib'], function ($,lib) {
    var lib = new lib();
    $(function () {
        //somecode
    })
});
```

the run result is fine

why?

Comment: Did you try [the official documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html)? Does it answer your question? If not, why?

Comment: it's my fault, thanks !

Comment: @Chengyu Please share why :)

Answer (score 0):

> The other (recommended) solution is to just name the file 'jquery.js'
>   and place it in the baseUrl directory. Then the above paths entry is
>   not needed. You can avoid lots of configuration lines by placing the
>   files according to the default ID-to-path convention of baseUrl +
>   moduleID + '.js'. The examples below show how to set baseUrl to be the
>   directory for third-party, library code, and use one extra paths
>   config for your app code. So to reiterate, you will likely get an
>   error if you refer to jQuery with another module name, like
>   'lib/jquery'. This example will not work:
>
> ```
> // THIS WILL NOT WORK
> define(['lib/jquery'], function ($) {...});
> ```

From http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html